# How to return an exception from a method called with .await()

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm implementing with the new google services coroutines extension functions to return an exception from an asynchronous call

```
suspend fun saveUserToken(user: User): Resource<Boolean> {
    val result = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.await()
    user.deviceToken = result.token
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user").document(user.uid).set(user).await()
    return Resource.success(true)
}
```

Here I do two asynchronous operations, first one retrieves the user device token, and the second one stores that device token + user data into Firestore

Now my question is.

**How do I know or return an exception from these two methods if one is throw ?**

Since is a Task, the exception should return in a form of the same object, I have read the .await() method to see how it handles the exceptions

```
public suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T {
    // fast path
    if (isComplete) {
        val e = exception
        return if (e == null) {
            if (isCanceled) {
                throw CancellationException("Task $this was cancelled normally.")
            } else {
                result
            }
        } else {
            throw e
        }
    }

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        addOnCompleteListener {
            val e = exception
            if (e == null) {
                if (isCanceled) cont.cancel() else cont.resume(result)
            } else {
                cont.resumeWithException(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are two types of exception, one is the task exception from where its called (this is the exception I want to catch in my first code block) and the second is the CancellationException which triggers when the coroutine is cancelled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use try/catch like you would with any other code:

```
try {
    val result = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.await()
    user.deviceToken = result.token
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user").document(user.uid).set(user).await()
    return Resource.success(true)
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    // handle the error here
}
```

Or you can put the try/catch around the call to `saveUserToken`.  In either case, if a suspend fun inside the try catch yields an error, your catch will trigger.

I suggest reading the documentation on [exception handling with Kotlin coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html).

Comment: Thanks Doug, last question, if I have more than one exception thrown inside this method, should be ok to wrap them all inside Exception, or should I catch multiple ones there with the name of the exact exception ?

Comment: Depends on what you need to know about or do with each exception.  Do whatever suits you, just like any other try/catch.

Comment: thanks, it justs needs to block the user and let a friendly message, I think with Exception will be ok, since if one of the two fails, the other one does not complete and at that point I will have just 1 exception thrown

Comment: It lets the user a friendly message and I log the error to Firebase crashlytics to better understand what is happening